# How to export function and import react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I know and know how to do it but it causes problems for me
I just want to import the functions `{OnSubmitLog_In and username}`  and maybe more how to listing it right is not going to make it a problem

2 js files

the first is imports like this

```
import * as Login from './log_in';
import { OnSubmitLog_In, username } from './log_in';
```

In the second file

```
async function OnSubmitLog_In(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = { username, password }
    await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users/signin", data, {
    }).then((response) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token', response.data.accessToken)) {
            alert('user alredy in')
        } else {
            alert('hellow ' + data.username)
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken)
            console.log('response data', response.data)
            console.log('response config', response.config.data)
        }


    }, (error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
        if (405) {
            alert('user not found')
        } else if (500) {
            alert('user not found try again')
        }
    });
}
export default Log_In;
```

this is the error

> ./src/NAVBAR/nav.js
>   Attempted import error: 'OnSubmitLog_In' is not exported from './log_in'.

Comment: looks like you are not exporting `onSubmitLog_In` from `log_in` file as the error says

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are exporting as `default`, you should import like this,

```
import OnSubmitLog_In from './log_in';  //Not sure about username
```

---

**Update**

To import everything from a single file as,

```
import * as Login from './log_in'
```

You need to export everything as `named export` from `log_in` file.

For example, this is my `log_in` file,

```
import React from 'react'


export const MyComponent = () => {
  return <div>Component 1</div>
}
export const MyComponent2 = () => {
  return <div>Component 2</div>
}
```

Now you can use those components in parent component like,

```
<Login.MyComponent />
<Login.MyComponent2 />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lbqytl)

Comment: what do you mean by *shorter way*?

Comment: import * as Login from './log_in'; like this

Comment: For that read this- https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910

Comment: If you have multiple named export in your file then you can use that shorter way.

Comment: @ItzikSaviya, check the updated answer and demo link.

Answer (score 0):

You should export you functions in an object to import them the way you do.

Like this:

```
async function OnSubmitLog_In(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = { username, password }
    await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/users/signin", data, {
    }).then((response) => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token', response.data.accessToken)) {
            alert('user alredy in')
        } else {
            alert('hellow ' + data.username)
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.accessToken)
            console.log('response data', response.data)
            console.log('response config', response.config.data)
        }


    }, (error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
        if (405) {
            alert('user not found')
        } else if (500) {
            alert('user not found try again')
        }
    });
}
export {
  OnSubmitLog_In
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `import` code as below.

```
import OnSubmitLog_In, { username } from './log_in';
```

Here you are exporting as `default`. If you remove `default` then you have to write code as below.

```
import { OnSubmitLog_In, username } from './log_in';
```